# How can I align TikZ nodes of a commutativity diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, tikz-arrows, commutative-diagrams

I have a Ti*k*Z picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=0em,column sep=3em,minimum width=2em] {
     E_1 & H^+ \\
     E_1^\perp & H^- \\
     &\R^{2m}\backslash\left\{H^+\cap H^-\right\}\\};
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge (m-1-2)
    (m-2-1) edge (m-2-2)
            edge (m-1-2)
            edge (m-3-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So far so good. It looks like this:

[image]

Two questions:

1. How can I align the the right nodes horizontally to the left, so that the left side of the right nodes is on one vertical line?
2. How can I align the right or left nodes vertically, so that the two horizontal arrows are exactly horizontal? Right now they are a little tilted.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default a `matrix of nodes` anchors (place and align) nodes on their `baseline`, but you can change it fixing a new anchor point:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=0em,column sep=3em,minimum width=2em, nodes={anchor=west}] {
     E_1 & H^+ \\
     E_1^\perp & H^- \\
     &R^{2m}\backslash\left\{H^+\cap H^-\right\}\\};
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge (m-1-2)
    (m-2-1) edge (m-2-2)
            edge (m-1-2)
            edge (m-3-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But now the lowest arrow doesn't end in the middle of the right element's side. How to correct this?

Comment: @Rob   `edge (m-3-2)` finishes the line at node's center but stops drawing it a node's hidden border. Same happens with line going to H+ from second line. A possible solution could be `edge (m-3-2.west)` which will finish at central point on node's west border.

Answer (score 4):

A version with `tikz-cd`; only a small adjustment needs to be made for an arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[
  cells={nodes={anchor=west}},
  end anchor={west},
  row sep=1ex,
  column sep=large,
]
E_1 \arrow[r] & H^+ \\
E_1^\perp
  \arrow[ru,end anchor=south west]
  \arrow[r]
  \arrow[rd] & H^- \\
& \mathbb{R}^{2m}\setminus (H^+\cap H^-)
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal version using `tikz-cd` package.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2mm, column sep=1.5cm, cells={anchor=west}]
    E_1 \arrow[r]   & H^+ \\
    E_1^\perp \arrow[ur]\arrow[r]\arrow[dr, end anchor={west}] & H^- \\
    & \mathbb{R}^{2m} \setminus\left\{H^+\cap H^-\right\}\ \\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```